# Redirect http traffic to https using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, cloudflare

I'm trying to redirect all http traffic to https. I've not installed and SSL certificate on my server and is using the cloudflare flexible SSL option.

The following code works file

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this redirects http://www.example.com to https://example.com

However when I add this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to redirect all non www urls, like http://example.com to https://example.com

The site doesn't load and gives me an error saying **Too many redirects** on the browser. How can I fix this and redirect all my http traffic to https://?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no SSL certificate on your server, you must set CloudFlare SSL to "flexible".

According to their [blog post](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-HTTPS-traffic-with-Flexible-SSL-and-Apache-) you can then set the following in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Your current setting checks if the request comes to **your** server via https, but since you don't have a certificate, that can't work. CloudFlare forwards all https-requests to http, your server then redirects to https and so on.